# Unable to substitute escaped characters in string

Tags: ruby

I have this string:

```
str = "no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\""
 => "no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\""
```

I want to remove the escaped double quoted string character `\"`. I use `gsub`:

```
result = str.gsub('\\"','')
 => "no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\""
```

It appears that the string has not substituted the double quote escape characters in the string.

Why am I trying to do this? I have this csv file:

```
no,"contact_last_name","token",company,urbanization,sec-"property_address","property_address",city-state-zip,ase,oel,presorttrayid,presortdate,imbno,encodedimbno,fca,"property_city","property_state","property_zip"
1,MARIE A JEANTY,1083123,,,,17 SW 6TH AVE,DANIA BEACH FL 33004-3260,Electronic Service Requested,,T00215,12/14/2016,00-314-901373799-105112-33004-3260-17,TATTTADTATTDDDTTFDDFATFTDDDTTFADTTDFAAADDATDAATTFDTDFTTAFFTTATFFF,017,DANIA BEACH,FL, 33004-3260
```

When I try to open it with CSV, I get the following error:

```
CSV.foreach(path, headers: true) do |row|
end
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.
```

Once I removed those double quoted strings in the first row (the header), the error went away. So I am trying to remove those double quoted strings before I run it through CSV:

```
file = File.open "file.csv"
contents = file.read
"no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\" ... "
contents.gsub!('\\"','')
```

So again my question is why is gsub not removing the specified characters? Note that this actuall does work:

```
contents.gsub /"/, ""
```

as if the string is ignoring the \ character.

Comment: what about string.delete('"\')

Comment: @Brad I think I found the solution: contents.gsub /"/, ""

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Please don't use a link to the required input data, instead reduce it to the bare minimum necessary to duplicate the problem. Links rot then break, and when they do the question won't be nearly as useful as it will be if you make it self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no escaped double quote in this string:

```
"no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\""
```

The interpreter recognizes the text above as a string because it is enclosed in double quotes. And because of the same reason, the double quotes embedded in the string must be escaped; otherwise they signal the end of the string.

The enclosing double quote characters are part of the language, not part of the string. The use of backslash (`\`) as an escape character is also the language's way to put inside a string characters that otherwise have special meaning (double quotes f.e.).

The actual string stored in the `str` variable is:

```
no,"contact_last_name","token"
```

You can check this for yourself if you tell the interpreter to put the string on screen (`puts str`).

---

To answer the issue from the question's title, all your efforts to substitute escaped characters string were in vain just because the string doesn't contain the character sequences you tried to find and replace.

---

And the actual problem is that the CSV file is malformed. The 6th value on the first row (`sec-"property_address"`) doesn't follow the format of a correctly encoded CSV file.

It should read either `sec-property_address` or `"sec-property_address"`; i.e. the value should be either not enclosed in quotes at all or completely enclosed in quotes. Having it partially enclosed in quotes confuses the Ruby's CSV parser.

Answer (score 1):

The string looks fine; You're not understanding what you're seeing. Meditate on this:

```
"no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\"" # => "no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\""
'no,"contact_last_name","token"'     # => "no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\""
%q[no,"contact_last_name","token"]   # => "no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\""
%Q#no,"contact_last_name","token"#   # => "no,\"contact_last_name\",\"token\""
```

When looking at a string that is delimited by double-quotes, it's necessary to escape certain characters, such as embedded double-quotes. Ruby, along with many other languages, has multiple ways of defining a string to remove that need.